# Resampling on a multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the following form:
[image]

You see that it has a multi index. For each `muni` index I want to do a resampling of the form `.resample('A').mean()` of the `popDate` index. Hence, I want python to fill in the missing years. NaN values shall be replaced by a linear interpolation. How do I do that?

Update: Some mock input DataFrame:

```
interData=pd.DataFrame({'muni':['Q1','Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q2'],'popDate':['2015','2021','2022','2015','2017','2022'],'population':[5,11,22,15,17,22]})
interData['popDate']=pd.to_datetime(interData['popDate'])
interData=interData.set_index(['muni','popDate'])
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input (not an image!)

Comment: @mozway Thanks for your comment. Sure, that makes testing easier for you. I have done so and updated my question.

Comment: @ScottBoston See my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [`groupby.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
interData.groupby(level='muni').resample('A', level='popDate').mean()
```

Output:

```
                 population
muni popDate               
Q1   2015-12-31         5.0
     2016-12-31         NaN
     2017-12-31         NaN
     2018-12-31         NaN
     2019-12-31         NaN
     2020-12-31         NaN
     2021-12-31        11.0
     2022-12-31        22.0
Q2   2015-12-31        15.0
     2016-12-31         NaN
     2017-12-31        17.0
     2018-12-31         NaN
     2019-12-31         NaN
     2020-12-31         NaN
     2021-12-31         NaN
     2022-12-31        22.0
```

If you also need interpolation, combine with [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
out = (interData.groupby(level='muni')
       .apply(lambda g: g.resample('A', level='popDate').mean()
                         .interpolate(method='time'))
      )
```

Output:

```
                 population
muni popDate               
Q1   2015-12-31    5.000000
     2016-12-31    6.001825
     2017-12-31    7.000912
     2018-12-31    8.000000
     2019-12-31    8.999088
     2020-12-31   10.000912
     2021-12-31   11.000000
     2022-12-31   22.000000
Q2   2015-12-31   15.000000 # 366 days between 2015-12-31 and 2016-12-31
     2016-12-31   16.001368 # 365 days between 2016-12-31 and 2017-12-31
     2017-12-31   17.000000
     2018-12-31   17.999452
     2019-12-31   18.998905
     2020-12-31   20.001095
     2021-12-31   21.000548
     2022-12-31   22.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks very good. But I have still one question: Coming from the input data a true linear interpolation would assign about 15.99 to the Q2 value of 2015-12-31 (since we have 15.0 at the start of the year 2015-01-01). Is there a possibility to get such a true interpolation?

Comment: Yes, you have to temporarily change the order of the index. Actually I would make it always sorted by date first then quarter, this seems more logical ;)

Comment: That's a very stange output and not what I expected. Q1 and Q2 are completely independend from each other. Let us focus on Q2 only. There I would expect every value from your first interpolation being almost 1 higher (actually 364/365 in normal and 365/366 in leap years) because the data we provide apply to Jan 1st, but we want to interpolate Dec 31st.

Comment: I see what you mean, I had misunderstood what you wanted, I thought Q1/Q2 were related. Check if the update is what you want, it now takes into account the days

Comment: Actually what kind of data does the value represent? the interpolation should be a bit above 16 as there is one more day before 2016-12-31 than after. If you want to split the values per day, then you would need to take the inverse before/after interpolation: `.rdiv(1).interpolate(method='time').rdiv(1)` yielding `15.938863`.

Comment: Let's look at the given data (only for Q2): We have given the value 15 at 2015-01-01 and the value 17 at 2017-01-01. Hence by linear interpolation we should have 15.99... at 2015-12-31 and 16.99... at 2016-12-31. This mistake happens already in the resampling function (because it does not interpolate at all). But I'm to new to python pandas to know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the complete expected output?

Comment: Sure, shall we do that in a new thread since the question of this thread was perfectly solved by you? In this thread here I was only concerned about the grouping and only used the possibilty to ask the other question about the interpolation.

Comment: Sure, as you wish

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112453/actual-interpolation-based-on-date