# Actual interpolation based on date

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

This question here is a follow up question occurred in the comments of [Resampling on a multi index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75110993/2706344).

We start with following data:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2004','2008','2012'],'values':[k*(1+4*365) for k in range(3)]})
data['dates']=pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])
data=data.set_index('dates')
```

That is what it produces:
[image]

Now, when I resample and interpolate by

```
data.resample('A').mean().interpolate()
```

I obtain the following:
[image]

But what I want (and the problem is already the resampling and not the interpolation step) is

```
2004-12-31     365
2005-12-31     730
2006-12-31    1095
2007-12-31    1460
2008-12-31    1826
2009-12-31    2191
2010-12-31    2556
2011-12-31    2921
2012-12-31    3287
```

So I want an actual linear interpolation on the given data.

To make it even clearer I wrote a function which does the job. However, I'm still looking for a build in solution (my own function is bad coding because of a very ugly runtime):

```
def fillResampleCorrectly(data,resample):
    for i in range(len(resample)):
        currentDate=resample.index[i]
        for j in range(len(data)):
            if currentDate>=data.index[j]:
                if j<len(data)-1:
                    continue
            valueBefore=data[data.columns[0]].iloc[j-1]
            valueAfter=data[data.columns[0]].iloc[j]
            dateBefore=data.index[j-1]
            dateAfter=data.index[j]
            currentValue=valueBefore+(valueAfter-valueBefore)*((currentDate-dateBefore)/(dateAfter-dateBefore))
            resample[data.columns[0]].iloc[i]=currentValue
            break
```

Comment: Can you provide the full output? for 2009/2010 as well. It looks to me that a simple shift it expected

Comment: @mozway Sure, I edited it. Is the principal not clear to you? It's just linear interpolation by the given data. I chose the values in such a way that we don't have to deal with decimals. It's just the number of days after 2004-01-01 in this example.

Comment: Yes I got it, I'm busy IRL at the moment, I'll have a look a bit later!

Comment: Thanks a lot and take your time. I guess I could write a little program on my own which does the job. But I think the power of pandas probably provides this already.

Comment: @mozway I just wrote the little program (see the edit of my question).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a direct way with just resample

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a direct way for your exact output. The issue is the resampling between the 01-01 and 31-12 of the first year.

You can however mimick the result with:

```
out = data.resample('A', label='right').mean().interpolate(method='time') + 365
```

Or:

```
s = data.resample('A', label='right').mean().interpolate(method='time')

out = s + (s.index[0] - data.index[0]).days
```

Output:

```
            values
dates             
2004-12-31   365.0
2005-12-31   730.0
2006-12-31  1095.0
2007-12-31  1460.0
2008-12-31  1826.0
2009-12-31  2191.0
2010-12-31  2556.0
2011-12-31  2921.0
2012-12-31  3287.0
```

Comment: Your mimick does only work because of my very special choice of data points for the sake of the easiness to understand and predict the values in my example. My actual data looks wild and my data points are not always at the start of a year. They are more or less randomly distributed over the year.

Answer (score 0):

What is “actual” interpolation? You are considering leap years, which makes this a non-linear relationship.

Generating a df that starts with the end of the year (and accounts for 2004 as a leap year):

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2004-12-31', '2008-12-31', '2012-12-31'], 'values': [
                    366 + k * (1 + 4 * 365)  for k in range(3)]})
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])
data = data.set_index('dates')
```

```
            values
dates   
2004-12-31  366
2008-12-31  1827
2012-12-31  3288
```

Resample and interpolation as before (`data = data.resample('A').mean().interpolate()`). By the way, `A` in resample is end of year, and `AS` is start of year.
If we look at the difference between each step (`data - data.shift(1)`), we get:

```
            values
dates   
2004-12-31  NaN
2005-12-31  365.25
2006-12-31  365.25
2007-12-31  365.25
2008-12-31  365.25
2009-12-31  365.25
2010-12-31  365.25
2011-12-31  365.25
2012-12-31  365.25
```

As we would expect from a linear interpolation.
The desired result can be achieved by applying `np.floor` to the results:

```py
data.resample('A').mean().interpolate().apply(np.floor)
```

```
            values
dates   
2004-12-31  366.0
2005-12-31  731.0
2006-12-31  1096.0
2007-12-31  1461.0
2008-12-31  1827.0
2009-12-31  2192.0
2010-12-31  2557.0
2011-12-31  2922.0
2012-12-31  3288.0
```

And the difference `data - data.shift(1)`:

```
            values
dates   
2004-12-31  NaN
2005-12-31  365.0
2006-12-31  365.0
2007-12-31  365.0
2008-12-31  366.0
2009-12-31  365.0
2010-12-31  365.0
2011-12-31  365.0
2012-12-31  366.0
```

A non-linear relationship caused by the leap year.

Comment: My example is of course a simplified version of that real data I have. In my actual data my data points are not always at the start of a year. They are randomly distributed over the year and in my interpolation I want to normalize it such that I have one data point for each year. The interpolation should then respect at which days in the year the data is known.

Comment: About your first question "What is “actual” interpolation?": The system knows quite well that certain years are longer than others. Look at the code provided by me at the end of my question. There I use the systems knowledge to compute with time to make the right linear interpolation: `currentValue=valueBefore+(valueAfter-valueBefore)*((currentDate-dateBefore)/(dateAfter-dateBefore))`

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with an idea and it works:

```
dailyData=data.asfreq('D').interpolate()
dailyData.groupby(dailyData.index.year).tail(1)
```

Only for the last year the wrong date is chosen, but that is completely fine for me. The important thing is that the days match to the values.